# Reasoning with pattern matchings in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

If I have a hypothesis of the form

```
H: match G with
   | C x => e
   | _ => None
   end = Some T
```

How can I deduce `G = C x` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please submit complete examples; likely in your case `destruct G; congruence` should do the trick.